PowerTOP on a Server and UPS: cannot load from file
I am trying to reduce power consumption of my Ubuntu Server. I installed PowerTOP and ran it with —-calibrate flag. I am always getting an error why trying to use —auto-tune:
modprobe cpufreq_stats failed
Loaded 0 prior measurements
Cannot load from file /var/cache/powertop/saved_parameters.powertop
File will be loaded after taking minimum number of measurement(s) with battery only 
RAPL device for cpu 0
RAPL Using PowerCap Sysfs : Domain Mask d
RAPL device for cpu 0
RAPL Using PowerCap Sysfs : Domain Mask d
Devfreq not enabled
glob returned GLOB_ABORTED
Cannot load from file /var/cache/powertop/saved_parameters.powertop
File will be loaded after taking minimum number of measurement(s) with battery only 
Leaving PowerTOP

I tried both this and this answer but no matter what I do no measurements are saved.
When PowerTOP asks to make measurements with battery only, I try disconnecting the UPS, the server connected to, from the main power and then run calibrate or leave PowerTOP running. I have been trying with it for weeks but could not find an answer.
Any help is greatly appreciated!
